# Pygame delete non sprite objects

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games

So Im trying to make an upward scrolling platformer, and I need a way to delete the score counter and hide the death screen when a player dies and restarts. However, those objects aren't sprites. Is there still a way to delete them?

Comment: The scene is redrawn in every frame. "Deleting" an object just means not drawing it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just an example because you have not provided any code :'(

```
if not ondeathscreen:
     #draw your deathscreen
if not inGame:
     #draw your score counter
```

you have to personilize this code with your game but hopefully it helps :))).